# Question about factorization of ${ {x+n} \choose n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, factoring

Let $x,n$ be integers with $x \ge n > 2$

Let $v_p(n)$ be the highest power of $p$ such that $p^{v_p(n)} \le n < p^{v_p(n)+1}$.

Assume that for a given prime $p$ such that $2 < p \le n$, none of the $n$ integers $x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n$ is divisible by $p^{v_p{n}+1}$

Does it then follow that $p^{v_p{n}+1} \nmid {{x+n} \choose n}$?

Here's an example of what I am talking about:

> Let:
>
> - $x = 11$
> - $n = 10$
> - $p = 3$
>
> $v_3(10) = 2$, and $27$ does not divide any integer in the set $\{ 11, 12, \dots, 21 \}$
>
> Likewise, $27$ doesn't divide ${ {21} \choose {10}}$

To analyze this case, we only need to consider the following ratio:  $\frac{3*3*9*3}{3*3*9}$.  In this case, $9 \nmid {{21} \choose {10}}$.

I suspect that it is a simple argument to generalize this result. Am I wrong?

---

Edit 1:  I've had some thoughts which, if true (I still need to prove them), would resolve my question.  I believe all of these points are true.

I would greatly appreciate it if either someone can point out where I am wrong or help me to understand how to improve my argument so that it is less wordy and more mathematically precise.

Note: In all cases, I'm assuming that no integer in $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ is divisible by $p^{v_p(n)+1}$ and no integers in $\{x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n\}$ is divisible by $p^{v_p(n)+1}$

> (1)  If the number of integers divisible by $p$ in the set $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ is the same as the number of integers divisible by $p$ in the set $\{x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n\}$, then the maximum power of $p$ that divides ${{x+n} \choose {n}}$ is $p^{v_p{n}-1}$.
>
> (2)  If the number of integers divisible by $p$ in $\{1, 2, \dots n\}$ is different than the number of integers divisible by $p$ in $\{x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n \}$, then the difference in number of integers divisible by $p$ is $1$.
>
> (3) If the number of integers divisible by $p$ in $\{1, 2, \dots n\}$ is less than the number of integers divisible by $p$ in $\{x+1, x+2, \dots x+n\}$, then the maximum power of $p$ that divides ${{x+n} \choose {n}}$ is $p^{v_p{n}}$.

Comment: Perhaps, Kummer's theorem helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I was not familiar with Kummer’s Theorem.  That is exactly what I was looking for!